# Using 5V microphone module with Wemos D1 Mini Pro 3.3V analog pin

Tags: voltage-level

I want to read values from [this microphone module](https://tkkrlab.nl/wiki/Arduino_KY-038_Microphone_sound_sensor_module) using Wemos D1 Mini Pro analog pin. Unfortunately, this module operates on 5V, but the analog pin on Wemos has range 0-3.3V. I have tried to use a voltage divider on microphone module output, but I am getting very low values which don't reflect sound power (to get values greater than zero I have to knock on the microphone). In the voltage divider R1 = 500 Ohm and R2 = 1000 Ohm. **Is there some way to make this work correctly?**

Comment: What are the output impedance of the module and the input impedance of the Wemos pin?

Comment: Wemos: < 100 Kohm (http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?p=61759#p61759). About the module I am not sure, but I have found page with more info: http://sensorkit.en.joy-it.net/index.php?title=KY-038_Microphone_sound_sensor_module . I can tell you the resistance of that potentiometer: 66.4 Kohm